# SaveAs: Invalid PDF file format

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I am using easyPDF 7

I am following [this](http://www.pdfonline.com/easypdf/sdk/programming-pdf/csharp/) guide. When I try to edit a field then save I get the following error:

```
"SaveAs: Invalid PDF file format"
```

If I don't try and edit the field I can call the SaveAs method without error.

Here is my code

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("easyPDF.Loader.7");
Loader oLoader = (Loader)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

PDFDocument oDocument = (PDFDocument)oLoader.LoadObject("easyPDF.PDFDocument.7");

oDocument.Open("C:/Acrobat Document.pdf");

FormFields oFormFields = oDocument.FormFields;

FormField oFormField = oFormFields[0];

TextField oTextField;
oDocument.SaveAs("C:/Acrobat Document.pdf"); //this save works


if (oFormField.Type == docFormFieldType.DOC_FRMTYPE_TEXT)
{ 
    oTextField = (TextField)oFormField;
    oTextField.Value = "BCL Technologies";//if I comment this line out I dont get the error
}


oDocument.SaveAs("C:/Acrobat Document.pdf");//this save throws error:SaveAs: Invalid PDF file format
```

Comment: Try to comment out the first `oDocument.Open("C:/Acrobat Document.pdf");`. Is the error still available?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan If he doesn't open the file, there will be nothing to save!

Comment: ups, sorry, I mean **first** `oDocument.SaveAs("C:/Acrobat Document.pdf"); `.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan removing the first SaveAs() does not repair error.

Comment: What is the actual data in the `oTextField`?

Comment: Before I update it: "###EntityName"

Comment: I assume, that the field with value `###EntityName` is something which in terms of `easyPDF` called `special appearance field`. http://www.pdfonline.com/easypdf/sdk/usermanual/reference/pdfdocumentsdk/textfield/p_value.htm